# Use ozonated distilled water for maintenance-free batteries?

Tags: battery

It's written everywhere that you should use Distilled water for topping up the electrolyte levels in the batteries; however, it would appear that Walmart's Distilled water also goes through Ozonation, in addition to Steam Distillation.

There are some folklore stories that using such Great Value Distilled water kills the batteries for good.  Is that true or false?  Should such water be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Ozone is used only as a purifying agent.  Ozone decomposes irreversibly in water to form O2 (2 O3 -> 3 O2).  That is, when you buy the water, any ozone that was in the water is long gone and therefore you don't need to worry about it.

Distilled and de-ionized water are NOT the same thing.  Distilled is boiled and then the steam condensed (as described in the other answer).  There is virtually nothing in such water (it will quickly absorb gas from the air and dissolve any residue in the container used to hold it, but in principle it is pure).  It contains no ions *and nothing else* (actually, that isn't even quite true.... it does have H+ and OH- ions in equilibrium, but those aren't contaminants).

De-ionized water, on the other hand, has had all its *ions* removed (all contaminant ions).  Not all water soluble substances ionize in water.  So, it is possible for de-ionized water to have non-ionic compounds dissolved in the water (e.g. ethanol).  Compare that with distilled which in principle has nothing in it....  They are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The water you are describing should be just fine. Ozone is just oxygen with three molecules (O3) rather than two (O2). It is a gas and will dissipate from the battery rather quickly. It is put into the water to help keep it fresh. What you need is the distilled part of the water, which means it's just water without impurities of metal or such which would clog up the battery. This water should not cause you any issues.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone, Ozone is a powerful oxidant and is often used for oxidation.  Doesn't this imply that it has a much higher chance of oxidizing the plates, especially if they were exposed prior to adding the said distilled water?

Answer (score -1):

Distilled water and de-ionised water are the same thing. Water is boiled to cause it to evaporate, the steam is captured and cooled which turns it into back into water, pure water - distilled and de-ionised. Any impurities in the original water are left behind in the process. Ozonation of water is primarily used is waste water treatment as a oxidising disinfectant and its use in battery water is a complete non-sense.